How to Move Out of Stock Products to the Bottom and Available Products to the Top in Magento 2.4.7
How to Move Out of Stock Products to the Bottom and Available Products to the Top in Magento 2.4.7
After Magento 2.4.7 update
Out of stock products appeared at the top of the page, and the customer had to search all pages until he found the product
Previously, Out of Stock products were at the bottom of the page or under its own section

To achieve this, you'll need a third-party or custom module.
I recommend using the GhoSter_OutOfStockAtLast module, you can find it on GitHub at https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast
